# Mule is taking a long time for the simple select for the first execution

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I am just using a HTTP listener and Select in mule flow. It is a get method, passing ID as an input, and the same ID is passed to select (input). It is taking 3 to 4 minutes of delay when we execute via mule for the first time, but in DB, it took only millisecond.

**This delay only happens after adding the parameter in the select.**

Someone help me, why there is a delay for the first time and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause could be how you create Metadata. For example you use huge CSV file as example for your data structure. Mule reads whole file to have headers. It takes time.

Solution - if you create Metadata by example - use small examples with couple rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the main points that cause performance issues in first executions are:

- JVM and Mule Runtime warmup
- Time to establish connections

The first one can not be avoided. For the second one usually a connection pool is used to mitigate it somewhat. Having said that 4 minutes is a very excessive time for either of those. You need to do some performance analysis, adding logs before and after operation in the flow, enabling debug logs for the database connector and even using a Java profiler connected to the Mule JVM to understand what could be happening.

You also have to consider if there is a high number of records that need to be processed, even if the database can answer quickly, it might take some time to format.